# How to prove :For $a_i\in(0,1)$ ($i=1,\cdots,N$), then $\prod\limits_{i=1}^Na_i+\prod\limits_{i=1}^N\sqrt{1-a_i^2}\leq1.$

Tags: calculus, analysis

How to prove the following inequality:

For $a_i\in(0,1)$ ($i=1,\cdots,N$), N>1, then 
$$\prod\limits_{i=1}^Na_i+\prod\limits_{i=1}^N\sqrt{1-a_i^2}\leq1.$$

Thank you, GUYS!

Maybe try considering some trigonometric functions?

Comment: I think that for $N=1$ doesn't hold true. Take for example $a_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Yes, I add a patch N>1. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $N=2$, this is Cauchy-Schwarz: if $a_1^2+b_1^2=1$ and $a_2^2+b_2^2=1$, then
$$
a_1a_2+b_1b_2\leq (a_1^2+a_2^2)^{1/2}(b_1^2+b_2^2)^{1/2}=1.
$$
This suggests a proof by induction:
\begin{align}
\prod_{j=1}^{N+1}a_j+\prod_{j=1}^{N+1}\sqrt{1-a_j^2}&=(a_{N+1},\sqrt{1-a_{N+1}^2})\cdot\left(\prod_{j=1}^{N}a_j,\prod_{j=1}^{N}\sqrt{1-a_j^2}\right)\\ \ \\
&\leq (a_{N+1}^2+{1-a_{N+1}^2})^{1/2}\,\left(\prod_{j=1}^{N}a_j^2+\prod_{j=1}^{N}(1-a_j^2)\right)^{1/2}\\ \ \\
&=\left(\prod_{j=1}^{N}a_j^2+\prod_{j=1}^{N}(1-a_j^2)\right)^{1/2}\\ \ \\
&\leq\left(\prod_{j=1}^{N}a_j+\prod_{j=1}^{N}\sqrt{1-a_j^2}\right)^{1/2}\\ \ \\
&\leq1,
\end{align}
where in the second to last inequality we use the fact that if $t\in (0,1]$ then $t^2\leq t$, and in the last inequality we use the inductive hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks a million!! PS: In the second inequality, there is a small typo. But anyway, thank you very very much for your help.

Comment: Good thing you noticed, and I wouldn't call it small! Corrected now.